# How to properly commenting an overridden class or method

Tags: php, comments

What is the accepted best practice in commenting an overridden class or method.

1. Should the parent class or methods comments be copied and a short note added explaining why and how it was modified.
2. Should the @see tag be used to link to the parent element (php docblock)
3. Any other accepted standards

Comment: This is certainly a good question to ask, but it is opinionated by nature and is therefore not a good question to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah , this one need to be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the Documentator your using they should outline it in there specifics but if your using "php docblock" then yes use the @see one if not read the manual for the one your using

Answer (score 0):

Use  the `@see` tag, but add any info that may deviate from the extended/overridden class/method.  For example, the @author may be different, the method will do some additional stuff (assuming it's not defining an abstract method) so note this.